# iOS application on app store becomes unusable after two days

Tags: ios, iphone, debugging

An app I recently had approved for sale on the iTunes store has been getting feedback stating a complete breakdown after two days of use. The app works as intended and seemingly (due to it being accepted for distribution) doesn't have any obvious bugs that could cause this sort of strange behaviour an Apple tester might pick up on. Essentially after a few days of use, the app initiates with a completely blacked-out screen and isn't usable.

I can't seem to find anything regarding this problem when searching Google and have no clue where to begin attempting to fix this issue.

Any ideas or links to similar problems would be really helpful.

Comment: Does your test/development copy of the app crash after two days?

Comment: Have you tested your app on several types of devices and os versions? Do test with memory warnings on the simulator as well.

Comment: You should contact apple support explaing your problem, so they can run some tests.

Comment: Another thing you can check: was it created for iOS 5 or iOS 6? I Have an app created for iOS 5, when I built it with the new XCode I had your same problem.

Comment: If this is a frequent issue, you should start seeing crash logs appearing in iTunes Connect for the application, so that would be where I'd start in diagnosing this. Without any sort of crash log or similar data, we can only speculate as to the cause here.

Comment: create a release version of your app (not just normal debug!) and transfer this to an iphone. now you can test the SAME version as in the appstore

Comment: These comments are really helpful. The app was made in iOS 5 over a time period of about 6 months and I havn't updated xcode yet. I have tested it on the iPhone 3 and 4s and it worked the same on both. I'll distribute to a test device and see if I can replicate it. Cheers for the feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a frequent issue, you should start seeing crash logs appearing in iTunes Connect for the application, so that would be where I'd start in diagnosing this. Without any sort of crash log or similar data, we can only speculate as to the cause here. – Brad Larson